# How do I generate a Webservice Client in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, intellij-idea

I have to set up a connection to a webservice that I don't own, all I have is a link to the WSDL file. The webservice has only one method, and I need access to it. I'm trying to use the standard "Generate Java Code from Wsdl or Wadl" (or create New->Web Service Client, which ends up in the same spot)

When I enter the URL I have, the status line says "Wsdl url connection exception". If I put the url in a browser, it nicely displays the xml file, so the URL works. I have a similar problem trying to generate the code in eclipse, where it also refuses to acknowledge the URL.

It's the first time I do anything webservice related and it's driving me mad, how do I fix this?

Comment: I'd rather download the WSDL, put it into a project and then generate the client stubs based on the local file.

Comment: It worked! Well, it worked in eclipse, IntelliJ wanted to download more jars and then failed when doing so. But at least I have code to work with now.

Comment: i've switched from netbeans to intellij and am happy with it.but the maven integration with intellij is really not that cool. i can't even see the various clients i have in a maven project i can't change it with `jaxws-maven-plugin` not generate or refresh from the plugin. Like @Slyder said it tries to download jaxws jars etc and fails. So why does it download jars when `jaxws-maven-plugin` is already there? is there anything that i should enabled? thanks

Comment: @Valyrion its also possible to generate the code from the terminal as well and then, you can use it in any IDE for the further usage.